# javascript if() dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have PHP and JS script for uploading image. PHP file returns a var `err:type` and I'm checking in JS `if return == err:type`, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        $('#avatar_image_upload_form').submit
        (
            function()
            {
                $('div#avatar_ajax_upload_demo img').attr('src','../../Files/Border/loading.gif');
            }
        );

        $('iframe[name=avatar_upload_to]').load(
            function()
            {
                var result = $(this).contents().text();
                if(result !='')
                {
                    $('div#avatar_ajax_upload_demo img').attr('src',result);
                    if(result == 'err:size')
                    {
                        $('div#avatar_ajax_upload_demo img').attr('src','../../Files/Border/avatar_big.jpg');
                    }
                    if (result == 'err:type')
                    {
                        $('div#avatar_ajax_upload_demo img').attr('src','../../Files/Border/avatar_invalid.jpg');
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

`if(result == 'err:type')` doesn't work, but `result = "err:type"`

Comment: Check the value of `result`, is it really `'err:type'`? Use `console.log(result)` or look at your network inspection tab.

Comment: "dont work" isn't helpful.  Are you saying that the condition doesn't match?  Or are you saying an error occurs on that line?  If it's the former (the condition doesn't match) then do as Frits suggests and either log `result` or `window.alert(result);` it.

Comment: yeah it is GET err:type  it says

Comment: Maybe you need to trim the string (remove whitespace from both ends of the string).

Comment: http://puu.sh/4T2mD.png

Comment: please, do not confuse `result == 'err:type'` with `result = 'err:type'`! the first is a comparison, the second an assignment

Comment: @cypherabe What makes you think he's making that mistake?

Comment: @Barmar the last line in the question, but maybe I read it wrong

Comment: I think he was just saying "the if doesn't work, but the variable is equal to err:type", but expressing it poorly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this image:

[image]

There are a lot of white lines at the beginning of the string. You need to trim the `result` string to remove them:

```
var result = $(this).contents().text().trim();
```

You should best fix your PHP code in order not to send those blank lines.

Comment: I thing the problem is in the PHP code... `trim` the result isn't the best solution for my part! but +1

Comment: @WalkerJetBat You really should fix the PHP that's putting all those extra newlines in the result in the first place.

Comment: Yes, (like I say earlier) the `trim` is just a patch.... Don't stay at this point! Try to retrieve the newlines insterted into the PHP code!

Answer (score -1):

[WRONG]
Maybe your error is here : (if `avatar_upload_to` isn't a variable)

```
$('iframe[name=avatar_upload_to]').load(
```

Should be

```
$('iframe[name="avatar_upload_to"]').load(
```

=====
[TEST]
What appends if you make this :

```
$('iframe[name=avatar_upload_to]').load(
        function()
        {
            var result = $(this).contents().text();
            console.log(result);
            //or
            alert(':'+result+':');
            if(result !='')
            {
                $('div#avatar_ajax_upload_demo img').attr('src',result);
                if(result == 'err:size')
                {
                    $('div#avatar_ajax_upload_demo img').attr('src','../../Files/Border/avatar_big.jpg');
                }
                if (result == 'err:type')
                {
                    $('div#avatar_ajax_upload_demo img').attr('src','../../Files/Border/avatar_invalid.jpg');
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: What's your PHP code sending this?? I'm sure the problem is in.

Comment: You only need quotes around `name="XXX"` if `XXX` contains special characters. It's never interpreted as a variable.

Comment: Yes you're right, if no special chars or spaces, you don't need quotes. I noted!